# Timber image resize of TinyPNG-compressed images produces bigger files than original

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

In my WordPress setup I use the TinyPNG plugin to compress uploaded images, which works very well when I used it with WordPress image sizes (`add_image_size()`). I now develop themes with Timber and use the resize function of `TimberImage` as it is much more convenient and does not generate every version for every image, which is never needed. The only problem is that resized image versions of the original compressed images are always bigger in file size than the original, especially for PNG files, because the `resize` function cannot save it with the same "compressed" algorithm. Does anyone have a solution to this problem other than moving back to `add_image_size()`?

Comment: I found a solution [here](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/857) by [KevinChassagne](https://github.com/KevinChassagne). There seems to also have been discussion for awhile on adding an image quality parameter to Timber's resize filter. It has not yet made it into the codebase though.